# how get result more than of 1024 in raven

Tags: ravendb

i Have This Code:

```
var query = sf + ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.filter) && model.filter != "none") ? "*" + model.filter + "*" : "*");
 var list = db.Advanced.DocumentQuery<Shop>();
list = list.AndAlso().Where(query);
```

my db is raven and I want to get all items of shop (items in shop are more than of 1024) for this i use this code:

```
           var o = 0;
            var g = new List<Shop>();
            do
            {
                var _list = list.Skip(o*1000).Take(1000);
                if(_list==null)
                  break;
                g.AddRange(_list);
                o++;
            }while(true)
```

problems:

1. _list never don't equal to null
2. for resolve this problem use this code      `if(_list.tolist().count()==0)break;`
   but skip don't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Raven Hilo in database for Intended ِDocument.
Path Documents>System Documents>Your Document